# NSFileManager Failing on create file

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

Here are my functions to save an image.

```
static func getDirectoryPath() -> String {
    let path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.picturesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true))[0]
    return path
}

static func savePhoto(with path: String, image: UIImage) {
    let fM = FileManager.default
    let path = getDirectoryPath() + path
    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
    let success = fM.createFile(atPath: path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
    print("File creation was \(success)")
}
```

and then I'm calling it like this

```
      let path = "/SpotCheck_\(spot.name)_Photo\(indx).jpg"
      PhotoManager.savePhoto(with: path, image: photo)
```

When I call create file is returns false every time and the photo is not saved.

EDIT: The problem was the second line needed to be documentDirectory instead of picturesDirectory. As shown below:

```
    let path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true))[0]
```

Comment: Is this iOS or macOS? And why use `FileManager` instead of the `Data write` method?

Comment: Have you checked your sandbox configuration?

Comment: This is for iOS, and I was not sure which method to use (file manager or write). I can try to see if write method will do what I want but do you have any idea why file manager wouldn’t work? Also is there a reason to use one method over the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS apps run in a sandbox. You can't write to the Pictures folder.

If you want to add a picture to the user's photo library then use `PHPhotoLibrary` or just `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

If you simply want to save the image within your own app then store the file in the Documents folder.

FYI - when using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` in iOS, the only useful directories are:

- libraryDirectory
- documentDirectory
- cachesDirectory
- applicationSupportDirectory

All the others are only useful in macOS.

Comment: Can I write an image to the document directory on iOS then? I want to persist photos in my application but not save them to users photo library.

Comment: That's quite different. Yes, the Documents folder is part of every app's sandbox and that is the normal place for an app to write its data. I've updated my answer for this.